# DTO classes, represent foreign keys on multiple values

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, dto

I have a question about DTO class representation. I have two tables on my database, where one has two foreign keys on another one, for example:

```
book(id, author_name, author_age)
author(name, age, telephone)
```

where book author_name and author_age are foreign keys on author name and age.

Generally what's the best way to implement this situation on a DTO class?
Inside Book DTO, it's better to do something like:

```
public class Book {
    private String id;
    private Author author;
}
```

or something like

```
public class Book {
    private String id;
    private String author_name;
    private int author_age;
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTO are objects that are being used for just transfering the values over communication channel most of time over http or https.

**Note** : Make your properties as public instead of private.

We should make it as simple as possible.

so use it like

```
public class Book {
    public String id;
    public String author_name;
    public int author_age;
}
```

> If you would compare the DTO without Author object vs DTO with Author object converted into json or xml, DTO without Author would be less in size.
>
> When using Author inside Book you just add extra wrapper (for author_name and author_age) which cost you some more over communication channel.

in case if Book have multiple authors or in case of one to many relationship you need to do like:

```
public class Book {
    public String id;
    public List<Author> authors;
}
```

**Note**:But make sure Author should not have a back property with Book instance like following.

```
public class Author
{
    public Book book;
}
```

in some client side framework like knockout it creates loop with observables.

Comment: Logically, only book should have references on author, and relationship is  one to one. probably i need to make some query of wich book has write an Author, but it's not about DTO layer

Comment: @giozh Yes DTO should be without Author to make it small in size see the updated answer.

Comment: @giozh it just creates extra wrapper that occupy more bandwidth.